# Passing data from view to net-mvc controller using AngularJS

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

```
 public class Home
{
    string CustEmail { get;set;}
    string CustName { get; set;}

    int id { get; set;}
}
```

Model

```
[HttpPost]
    public void CreateCustomer(Home cust)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

        }

    }
```

Controller

```
angular.module('myFormApp', []).controller('CustomerController', function ($scope, $http, $location, $window) {
    debugger;
    $scope.cust = {};
    $scope.message = '';
    $scope.result = "color-default";
    $scope.isViewLoading = false;

    //get called when user submits the form
    $scope.submitForm = function () {
        $scope.isViewLoading = true;
        console.log('Form is submitted with:', $scope.cust);
        //$http service that send or receive data from the remote server

        var cust = {
            CustEmail: $scope.cust.CustEmail,
            CustName: $scope.cust.CustName,
            id: 1,
        };

        $http(
        {
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/Home/CreateCustomer',
            data: cust,
        }).then(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.errors = [];
            if (data.success === true) {
                $scope.cust = {};
                $scope.message = 'Form data Submitted!';
                $scope.result = "color-green";
                $location.path(data.redirectUrl);
                $window.location.reload();
            }
            else {
                $scope.errors = data.errors;
            }
        })
        $scope.isViewLoading = false;
    }
}).config(function ($locationProvider) {
  //default = 'false'
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

I get the data in the proper format in front-end and the post-back call is also working but I cannot get value in MVC controller. I don't know what am I doing wrong. I have tried using the individual item in controller then it's working fine but i want it through model only.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `.then` method of a promise only exposes one value, not four values.

```
$http(
{
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/Home/CreateCustomer',
    data: cust,
̶}̶)̶.̶t̶h̶e̶n̶(̶f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶(̶d̶a̶t̶a̶,̶ ̶s̶t̶a̶t̶u̶s̶,̶ ̶h̶e̶a̶d̶e̶r̶s̶,̶ ̶c̶o̶n̶f̶i̶g̶)̶ ̶{̶
}).then(function (response) {
    var data = response.data;
    var status = response.status;
    var headers = response.headers;
    var config = response.config;
    $scope.errors = [];
    if (data.success === true) {
        $scope.cust = {};
        $scope.message = 'Form data Submitted!';
        $scope.result = "color-green";
        $location.path(data.redirectUrl);
        $window.location.reload();
    }
    else {
        $scope.errors = data.errors;
    }
})
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $http Service API Reference - returns](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#$http-returns)

---

### UPDATE

You can add a `.catch` block to console log any errors:

```
$http(
{
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/Home/CreateCustomer',
    data: cust,
̶}̶)̶.̶t̶h̶e̶n̶(̶f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶(̶d̶a̶t̶a̶,̶ ̶s̶t̶a̶t̶u̶s̶,̶ ̶h̶e̶a̶d̶e̶r̶s̶,̶ ̶c̶o̶n̶f̶i̶g̶)̶ ̶{̶
}).then(function (response) {
    var data = response.data;
    var status = response.status;
    var headers = response.headers;
    var config = response.config;
    $scope.errors = [];
    if (data.success === true) {
        $scope.cust = {};
        $scope.message = 'Form data Submitted!';
        $scope.result = "color-green";
        $location.path(data.redirectUrl);
        $window.location.reload();
    }
    else {
        $scope.errors = data.errors;
    }
    console.log("OK:", response.data);
}).catch(function(response) {
    console.log("ERROR:", response);
});
```

Comment: thank for changes.but what to know about post data is getting values as null on server.I not added headers in post request is it due to that

Comment: The AngularJS framework automatically adds `Content-Type: "application/json"` and encodes as JSON. The problem is not with the AngularJS code. You can add `.catch` block to console log any errors.

Comment: Ok.I will try it